# Как расположить форму регистрации под заголовком?

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  }

.reserv {
background-color: #f8e7d7;

}

.reserv__inner {
display: flex;

}


.reserv__content {
margin: 0 auto;

}
```

```html
<div class="reserv">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="reserv__inner">
            <img class="map" src="image/map__bg.jpg" alt="Картинка">
        
            <div class="reserv__content">
                <h4 class="form__suptitle">
                    RESERVATION
                </h4>
                <h2 class="form__title">
                    BOOKING A TABLE
                </h2>
            </div>  
         <div class="form">
                <div class="input__form">
                     <input type="text" placeholder="Имя">
                </div>

                <div class="input__form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Имя">
               </div>

               <div class="input__form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Имя">
           </div>
         </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто поместите форму в `div.reserv__content`

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  }

.reserv {
background-color: #f8e7d7;

}

.reserv__inner {
display: flex;

}


.reserv__content {
margin: 0 auto;

}
```

```html
<div class="reserv">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="reserv__inner">
            <img class="map" src="image/map__bg.jpg" alt="Картинка">
        
            <div class="reserv__content">
                <h4 class="form__suptitle">
                    RESERVATION
                </h4>
                <h2 class="form__title">
                    BOOKING A TABLE
                </h2>
                
               <div class="form">
                <div class="input__form">
                     <input type="text" placeholder="Имя">
                </div>

                <div class="input__form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Имя">
               </div>

               <div class="input__form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Имя">
           </div>
         </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```